# Explicit form of the smallest ball containing the origin and $n$ independent points.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, spheres

I am trying to understand the following claim.

**Claim.** Let $a_1, ..., a_n$ be $n$ points in $\mathbb R^d$, $d>n\geq 2$. We assume that $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ is [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). Let $y$ be a point in the [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of $a_1,..., a_n$ such that
$$\langle y-a_i, a_i \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } i=1,..., n. \tag{1}$$
Then the ball with diameter joining $y$ and $0_{\mathbb R^d}$ is the $\color{red}{\text{smallest}}$ ball containing $\{a_1, ..., a_n\} \cup \{0_{\mathbb R^d}\}$.

**My attempts.** First, the existence of $y$ is well defined. Indeed, if we let $y=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i$, then the system of linear equations $(1)$ has a unique solution $x=(x_i)_{i=1,...,n}$ by applying the [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Gram_determinant). Second, let $v_0=\frac{y}{2}$, then I can prove that $||y-v_0||=||0_{\mathbb R^d} -v_0||=||a_i-v_0||$ for all $i=1,..., n$, i.e. the ball with diameter joining $y$ and $0_{\mathbb R^d}$ already contained $\{a_1, ..., a_n\} \cup \{0_{\mathbb R^d}\}$.

**My question.** To prove the smallestness, we may consider $B(v_1, R)$ the smallest ball containing $\{a_1, ..., a_n\} \cup \{0_{\mathbb R^d}\}$ so as to $v_1\neq \frac{y}{2}$. How do I deduce a contradiction?

Comment: The claim is true for a (hollow) *sphere* but not always for a (solid) *ball*.

Comment: @WimC Thank you so much for your comment! It is quite intuitive for me if the claim hold true for hollow sphere then it will hold true for a solid ball. I really appreciate if you could give a counter example as an answer!

Comment: Take $(4,0,0)$ and $(2,1,0)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ for a counter example. The smallest ball has center $(2,0,0)$ but not all three points are on its boundary (the point $(2,1,0)$ lies in its interior).

Comment: @WimC yes, you are definitely right! Perhaps, the claim only holds true for sphere not a ball. I will re-check the claim. Thank you so much for your help!